# C++ implementation of binary multiplier

Tags: c++

I was trying out a C++ implementation of a 32 bits binary multiplier. I know just one way of doing this which is

```
    1011   (this is 11 in decimal)      
x   1110   (this is 14 in decimal)      
   ======        
    0000   (this is 1011 x 0)       
   1011    (this is 1011 x 1, shifted one position to the left)      
  1011     (this is 1011 x 1, shifted two positions to the left)     
 1011      (this is 1011 x 1, shifted three positions to the left)   
=========    
10011010   (this is 154 in decimal).
```

Is there another way to do it which is not so cumbersome to code as i have to do the operation over longer binary numbers?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_ALU#Implementations

Comment: If you need to multiply 32-bit numbers, why don't u use 64-bit type for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Booth's multiplication algorithm. There is more information on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Since the implicit multiplication for integral types is *binary multiplication*, you can utilize that directly to treat the digits as base 2<sup>8</sup>, 2<sup>16</sup> or higher, instead of base 2<sup>1</sup>.

If you assume 8-bit digits (multiplying `unsigned char`s) the 24-bit example below is less complex than the posted 4-bit multiply in your question.

```
           a1 a2 a3   (this is a 3 byte value)      
       x   b1 b2 b3   (this is another 3 byte value)      
           ======        
       xx xx xx xx    (this is a x b3)       
    xx xx xx xx       (this is a x b2, shifted 8 bits to the left)      
 xx xx xx xx          (this is a x b1, shifted 16 bits to the left)
 =================    
 xx xx xx xx xx xx    (this is the result).
```

You can replace "byte" in the above with `short` or `long`, with the shifts adjusted accordingly.

Just be sure the multiplicands are converted to a type large enough to hold the carry *before* multiplying.

Comment: Generally, you should have 6 digits in the product when you multiply 3-digit integer numbers.

Comment: A 3-digit integer times a 1-digit integer gives you a 4-digit integer, so, the intermediate results are longer as well and there should be 3 of them, not 4.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I have edited the visualization of this answer to no longer call those digits "carry".  Hopefully that will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by using loop to accomplish this.
Assume that the type `long` is 32 bits, so the result of long*long is 64 bits.

For example, if you have a `long A` ant a `long B`,and you want to compute `a*b`

First, you define the result as `long long result = 0;`.
Then check every bit of B,and if bit is 1, add `A << X` to result.Where X is the index of bit.
One loop can accomplish this.

```
long long AA = A;// convernt A to AA to avoid overflow
for( int index=0;i<32;++index )
{
    if( B & 0x1 )
        result += AA;
    AA <<= 1;
    B >>= 1;
}
```

I hope i didn't make mistake and this idea can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the (correct and efficient) implementation of arbitrary precision and big numbers **is** cumbersome and for use in production code it's generally good advise to rather use a tested framework for that (e.g., [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html), [gmp](http://gmplib.org/), etc).

However, if you implement it yourself, I would not store the number as a sequence of bits but as a sequence of machine words like `unsigned int` to make full use of your hardware ALU capabilities. So each word already represents a number of bits and your ALU knows how to multiply those.

Note, that when you multiply a number with `n` digits (the base is irrelevant), you will get a number with `2n` digits, e.g. 99 * 99 = 9801 (base 10), 0xFF * 0xFF = 0xFE01 (base 16).
So, if `std::uintmax_t` is `std::uint64_t` on your system you can store your number as a squence of `std::uint32_t`. When multiplying two digits convert them into `std::uint64_t` and multiply those. The upper 32 bits will be the part to carry to the multiplication for the next higher digits. (Actually, you can also multiply `std::uintmax_t` variables directly, but getting the high part of the result is normally a bit tricky and involves inline assembly in order to access the according `EDX\RDX` register.)

With this knowledge the implementation of the [school multiplication method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm) should be straightforward: Just iterate over all digits `a[i]` of number `a` and multiply every digit with number `b` (don't forget to propagate the carry). Shift the result up by `i` digits and add everything to your final result.

Note, that this algorithm has quadratic complexity regarding the number of primitive multiplications. If you have (very, very) large numbers you can also switch to more sophisticated methods like Karatsuba or even FFT and Schönhage–Strassen. But in this case, I would really recommend using a library instead.